# json parsing error for large data in browser

Tags: json, parsing

I am trying to perform an export to excel functionality from the data in an html table (5000+ rows).
 I am using json2.js for parsing the client side data in to json string called as jsonToExport.
 
The value of this variable is fine for less number of records and it is decoded fine (I checked in the browser in debug mode).
But for large dataset 5000+ records the json parsing/decoding is failing. I can see the encoded string but the decoded value shows:

```
jsonToExport: unable to decode
```

I experimented with the data and found that if the data exceeds a particular size then I get this error.
like increasing the column size or replacing large data columns with small length columns, so in effect its not an issue with the data format of encoded json string missing anything since all combination of columns work if the number of columns is limited.
Its definitely not able to decode/parse and then pass the json string in the request if its above a particular size limit.
Is there an Issue with json2.js which does the parsing (I think)?.
I also tried json3.min.js and received the same error.

Comment: I think this has some relevance to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9950377/2150268

Comment: Why do you need a library to create json from JavaScript? And what is json2.js anyway?

Comment: This link has some details on json3 and json2 http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Comment: My data size in MB may be like 1MB (actually less than that) for 5000+ rows, I checked the network call history in the chrome browser and it shows 732KB, so I am assuming its not related to maximum size of data that can be sent over the network, its just not parsing the data into a json object for large size data

Comment: The json2 library is being used in the system currently and has functions to parse data and provide a json string for the data.

Comment: Upon investigating the generated json, I see that the encoded json string is valid in browser, but the error comes up on decoded value of the json string.

Comment: But why use a library at all? What's wrong with [`JSON.parse(jsonString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing old browser support, like i.e. 7, you don't need to use antiquated libraries to parse JSON any longer, it's built in [`JSON.parse(jsonString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)